# I need help on the Java Scanner Code

Tags: java

So I need help on this code. This code is all in one so ignore the spaces but I need to write another scanner in the way bottom of the code and if I do add
`String feeling = in.nextLine();` at the very end it does not work. I need a it so that I can write my feelings so that I can make jarvis answer but the string does not work and java ignores the string and goes right on to the next part. It starts from the middle.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Type User Name:");
String userName = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("PASSWORD:");
int passcodeFromUser=in.nextInt();
int passcode = 2015;
if (passcodeFromUser == passcode) {
    System.out.println("Welcome Mr." + userName + "!");
    Random random = new Random(userName.hashCode());
    System.out.println("Mr." + userName + ", You are now recognized and you are now able to command me.");
    System.out.println("I was created by John Choi");
    System.out.println("JARVIS stands for Just A Rather Very Intelligent System");
    System.out.println("How are you today Mr." + userName + "?");
}
```

So if I add this code at the back it does not work. It ignores and says `Oh. Mr is feeling.`

```
String feeling = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Oh. Mr." + userName + "is feeling" + feeling + ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `nextInt` invocation does not actually parse a line feed.

Quoting the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29), `Scanner#nextInt`:

> Scans the next token of the input as an int.

(focus on the **token** part here)

Here's one (but not the only) way to fix it:

```
Integer passcodeFromUser = null;
try {
    passcodeFromUser= Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // TODO handle non-numeric password
}
```

... instead of `int passcodeFromUser=in.nextInt();`.

You can also loop the parsing of the `Integer` so that you print an error message when catching the `NumberFormatException` and don't break the loop until you have a valid numeric passcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the \n character:

```
in.nextLine();
String feeling = in.nextLine();
```

So just putting in.nextLine() before the code you were going to add will easily fix your problem.

Comment: @JohnTJC no problem, if you think my answer solved your problem, you can "choose" my answer as the solution so other people having your problem will know how to solve it :)